# jquery print object content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I'm new to jquery and want to print all times from monday only (or day == today later on)

I manage to print all times of the object and not 1 day I pick, maybe my iteration is wrong, would like any hints.

```js
var arr = [{
  "dateString": "2016-12-05",
  "weekday": "mon",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "15:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 15
  }, {
    "from": "17:00",
    "to": "20:00",
    "fromNumber": 17,
    "toNumber": 20
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-06",
  "weekday": "tue",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "17:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 17
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-07",
  "weekday": "wed",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "20:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 20
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-08",
  "weekday": "thu",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "1:00",
    "to": "11:00",
    "fromNumber": 1,
    "toNumber": 11
  }]
}];

$("button").click(function() {

  var today = new Date();
  var str = today.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy')
  var sta = str.substring(0, 4);
  console.log(sta);
  $.each(arr, function(i, currProgram) {
    $.each(currProgram.opening_hours, function(key, val) {
      //    $.each(num, function (axa, dasa) {
      if (currProgram.weekday == "mon") {
        console.log("monday");
        timefrom = (val.from);
        timeto = (val.to);
      } else {
        console.log("no monday");
      }
      // console.log(num[axa]);
      $(".result").append("\ntime: " + timefrom + " to " + timeto + "\n");
      console.log("time: " + timefrom + " to " + timeto + "\n");
      //    });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="calnote">
  <day></day>
  <br>
  <month></month>
  <blackcorner>
    <em>
        <time></time>
      </em>
  </blackcorner>
</p>

<div id="div1">
  <h2>click button for ajax</h2></div>
<div class="result">
  <br>
</div>result</div>
<br>
<div class="result1">

</div>result1</div>
<p class="calnote">
  <day></day>
  <br>
  <month></month>

  <blackcorner>
    <em>
        <time></time>
      </em>
  </blackcorner>
</p>
click event
<button class="abc">Click me</button> here
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jLxd7su/)

The result should print only:

> time: 09:00 to 15:00
>
> time: 17:00 to 20:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to move the logic `console.log("time: " + timefrom + " to " + timeto + "\n");` into the if block

```js
var arr = [{
  "dateString": "2016-12-05",
  "weekday": "mon",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "15:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 15
  }, {
    "from": "17:00",
    "to": "20:00",
    "fromNumber": 17,
    "toNumber": 20
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-06",
  "weekday": "tue",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "17:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 17
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-07",
  "weekday": "wed",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "09:00",
    "to": "20:00",
    "fromNumber": 9,
    "toNumber": 20
  }]
}, {
  "dateString": "2016-12-08",
  "weekday": "thu",
  "opening_hours": [{
    "from": "1:00",
    "to": "11:00",
    "fromNumber": 1,
    "toNumber": 11
  }]
}];

function buttonClick() {

  var today = new Date();
  var str = today.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy')
  var sta = str.substring(0, 4); 
  $.each(arr, function(i, currProgram) {
    $.each(currProgram.opening_hours, function(key, val) {      
      if (currProgram.weekday == "mon") {
        //console.log("monday");
        timefrom = (val.from);
        timeto = (val.to);       
       console.log("time: " + timefrom + " to " + timeto + "\n");      
      } else {
        //console.log("no monday");
      }      
    });
  });
}

buttonClick()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```